# PHP Sum (add numbers found) preg_match_all

Tags: php, sum

code works fine, it prints the prices found. But what do i to do add the results together. i do know how to make a sum but not for preg match

```
preg_match_all('/\$(.*?)<\/span>/is', $data, $matches); 
foreach($matches[1] as $price)
echo "$price<BR>";
}
```

would print

```
100
525.25
251.42
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

Comment: so so $sum = array($price); ? ?  i think they over complicated it

Comment: @newuser0250 Look at my answer it shows how to use it.

Comment: The way you're showing it, `$matches` you're assuming is full of floats. So, you should be able to do: `$prices = array_sum($matches);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = 0;
foreach($matches[1] as $price)
    $total += $price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `array_sum` function, and pass it the array of matches, in particular the entry `[1]` :

```
preg_match_all('/\$(.*?)<\/span>/is', $data, $matches); 
foreach($matches[1] as $price) {
   echo "$price<BR>";
}
/*This is the sum of the matched values*/
echo array_sum($matches[1]);
```

See it in action here: https://eval.in/753302

Comment: it only totals the very last results  as my script is in a foreach loop

Comment: Then you'll likely need to define a `$total` variable *outside* of your `foreach` loop, and keep adding to it the result of this `array_sum($matches[1])`.

Answer (score -1):

Since `$matches` is an array of all the matches, use [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) like Jared said:

```
$total = array_sum($matches);
echo $total;
```